# how to send simple text message using quickblox sdk?

Tags: sdk, quickblox

i am working with QBSimpleChat SDK . i wand to send simple group message . please help. here is my code . see what i am missing. thanks in advance.

QBChatMessage *inviteMessage = [QBChatMessage message];

```
        NSMutableDictionary *customParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        //customParams[@"xmpp_room_jid"] = roomJID;
        customParams[@"name"] = name;
        customParams[@"_id"] = senderId1;
        customParams[@"save_to_history"] = @YES;

        //customParams[@"type"] = 2;
        inviteMessage.senderID = senderId;
        inviteMessage.dateSent = [NSDate date];
        inviteMessage.senderNick = @"me";
        inviteMessage.text = text;

         customParams[@"occupants_ids"] = [occupides componentsJoinedByString:@","];
         NSString *afterSpace= [occupides componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
         NSUInteger num = [oneer integerValue];
         NSTimeInterval timestamp = (unsigned long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
         customParams[@"date_sent"] = @(timestamp);


        // send notification
        //
        inviteMessage.recipientID = num;

        //}
        inviteMessage.customParameters = customParams;







    [QBRequest createMessage:inviteMessage successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBChatMessage *createdMessage) {
        NSLog(@"success: %@", createdMessage);
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", response.error);
    }];
    [self.chatSectionManager addMessage:inviteMessage];

    [self finishSendingMessageAnimated:YES];
    NSLog(@"message for group is = %@",inviteMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send messages using the method of `QBChatDialog` instance :

```
- (void)sendMessage:(QB_NONNULL QBChatMessage *)message completionBlock:(QB_NULLABLE_S QBChatCompletionBlock)completion;
```

For more further explanation please follow [our guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Create_new_dialog).